# How to remove this Tab Space in VB6.0

Tags: xml, vb6

I have a XML file like this:

```
<root>
     <Sample>
           <Detail></Detail>
           <Test></Test>
     </Sample>
     </root>
```

How do I remove the tab space in the `</root>` tag?

I'm using VB6.0 and I used `createTextNode(vbNextLine + vbTab)` to create that format and the only problem I encounter is the last part which is the tab space in the `</root>` tag.

BTW, I'm using a loop to get the items under the Sample tag.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to keep the indentation on the `<Sample>` elements, adjust your code to add the newline and tab BEFORE the `<Sample>` element and just add a newline before the `</root>` element.

I'm also ignoring the fact that extra whitepace is irrelevant to XML.

Answer (score 0):

if CreateTextNode()  returns a string, or the xml content is temporally stored in a string variable or texbox  you can use Replace function:

```
replace(MyNode, vbtab & "</root>","</root>" )
```

or

```
replace(MyXml, vbtab & "</root>","</root>" )
```

or

```
replace(MyTexbox.text, vbtab & "</root>","</root>" )
```